# Weird behavior of Action in C#

Tags: c#, multithreading

I got a piece of code from my colleague which I am confused with. As per my limited knowledge of threads and actions, it can never happen that a timeout on the action didn't happen after BeginInvoke has been called when at the same time the code inside the action (more precisely an anonymous method here) didn't even start executing. But my colleague said that on one of the environments it is happening so. Therefore to just mimic it through code in which situation is this kind of output possible from the following code?

```
        IAsyncResult result;
        Action action = () =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Action started!!");
            Thread.Sleep(2000); // Assume a long running operation here which might take more than 15000 ms as well, resulting in timeout
            Console.WriteLine("Now the action got completed!!");
        };

        result = action.BeginInvoke(null, null);

        if (result.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne(15000))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Timeout didn't happen!!");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Timeout happened!!");
        }


        Console.WriteLine("Main thread continues to work!!");
```

Output:

========================

Timeout didn't happen!!

Main thread continues to work!!

========================

P.S. not even "Action started!!" is present in the output which is written before the long or time taking operation. **Also in real code the Console.WriteLine is replaced with writing the logs in a file.**

Edit:

- @Lasse Vågsæther Karlsen To provide some more context, by environment I mean different servers, the one on which it's showing this weird behavior is the production server so you can estimate it's having much more load and way more tasks to perform than a dev server or an internal test (on which this is working as expected).
- It's a WCF service and it's deployed and being run by admin user on respective servers.
- Also as I pointed out the logs are being written in a file and it's not a plain Console.WriteLine in the actual code (which I have not written or tested as it's that of my colleague). My instinct says that's where the problem is because of which not even "Action started!!" is written in the log file. Even a relevant link for this situation and even an alternative approach using Task would be helpful which guarantees non-weirdness!

Comment: What kind of application is this? Winforms? Console app? Web app? Service?

Comment: I doubt anyone is able to reproduce the problem from that code alone, there has to be something contextual which you're not telling us, as such you're going to have to debug more and figure out at least *some* differences between the environment it works in and one it doesn't. What does "environment" even mean here? Is it different servers? Different .NET versions (mono, .NET, .NET core, etc.), different users? There's **a lot** of information missing here.